# How do I remove "Preferences" & "Services" in menu bar on Mac in a NetBeans Platform Application?

Tags: macos, netbeans, menubar

I have built a (maven) NetBeans Platform Application using NetBeans 8.0.  In it, I have removed several menu items by editing the layer.xml file and doing something like:

```
<file name="Tools_hidden"/>
```

However, for the Mac OSX 10.9.4 platform I have two items that I'm not sure how to hide: Preferences, and Services.

In the XML Layer -> This layer in context -> Menu Bar, there are no items listed for these. I've tried something like:

```
<file name="Preferences_hidden>
<file name="Services_hidden>
```

but no success.

Does anyone know how to remove these items?

Thanks!